# Equal equivalence classes proof

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let there be two sets $A$ and $B$ and let their Cartesian product be $A{\times}B$. Let there be an equivalence relation $R:R\,{\subset}\,A{\times}B$. Let's define an equivalence class now: ${\lbrack}{\lbrack}a{\rbrack}{\rbrack}_R=\{b\,{\in}\,B:(a,b)\,{\in}\,R\}$

Let $[[x]]_R$ and $[[y]]_R$ be two such equivalence classes.

We know that $[[x]]_R=[[y]]_R$. How to use this to prove that $x\,R\,y$?

Comment: If $R$ is just a "relation" then we don't know it.  But if it is an equivalence relation, then we do.

Comment: How? Yes, it's supposed to be an equivalence relation.

Comment: Use the definition of $[[a]]_R$ given, and the definition of "equivalence relation".

Answer (score 1):

1. Equivalence relation is a subset of $A\times B$, not an element of it, so $R\notin A\times B$ but $R\subset A\times B$.
2. Equivalence relations are only defined in case $B = A$. An easy reminder is: any point must be equivalent to itself, so $(a,a)\in R$ for all $a\in A$. Of course that implies $R\subset A\times A$ (or at least $A\subset B$).
3. Since $(a,a)\in R$ for any $a$, $a \in [a]$. So if $[a] = [b]$ then $b\in [b]$ implies that $b\in [a]$, hence by definition $(a,b)\in R$.

Comment: What's your source on the equivalence relations being defined only if $A=B$? The source I'm using says nothing about that, it just says that they must be transitive, reflexive and symmetric.

Comment: Well, they can't be reflexive, aRa, unless a is in both A and B and $R \subset of (A \cap B) x (A \cap B)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $of(A∩B)x(A∩B)$?

Comment: Ilya has a point.  If $R \subset of A \times B$ then aRa implies $a \in A$ and $a \in B$ so $a \in A \cap B$ so R is a subset of the cross product of the intersections.  $R \subset A \cap B \times A \cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b \in [[x]]_R = [[y]]_R$.  Then $b R x$ and $b R y$.  By symmetry and transitivity $x R y$.